# mysql count distinct elements which you have in a list

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

In the recipie_ingredient table I have different ingredients.

```
create table recipe_ingredient (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    rel_recipe INT(6),
    rel_ingredient INT(6)
  );

INSERT INTO recipe_ingredient (rel_recipe, rel_ingredient) VALUES(1, 32);
INSERT INTO recipe_ingredient (rel_recipe, rel_ingredient) VALUES(1, 99);
INSERT INTO recipe_ingredient (rel_recipe, rel_ingredient) VALUES(1, 123);
INSERT INTO recipe_ingredient (rel_recipe, rel_ingredient) VALUES(1, 123);
INSERT INTO recipe_ingredient (rel_recipe, rel_ingredient) VALUES(1, 227);
INSERT INTO recipe_ingredient (rel_recipe, rel_ingredient) VALUES(1, 395);
INSERT INTO recipe_ingredient (rel_recipe, rel_ingredient) VALUES(1, 403);
INSERT INTO recipe_ingredient (rel_recipe, rel_ingredient) VALUES(1, 403);
```

Based on my ingredients I would like to get recipes which consist of my ingredients. I would like to get a number of unique ingredients in the recipe. In [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/XhZs8yAyvRkubyYCf1GiY/0) I created a table and insert demo data, I also add my current SQL which does not work properly.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(distinct(ri.rel_ingredient)) as allIngredient,
  sum((ri.rel_ingredient) in (123,403)) have
FROM recipe_ingredient ri
GROUP BY ri.rel_recipe;
```

The final result should be **allIngredient**: 6 and **have**: 2. ([DB Fiddle link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/XhZs8yAyvRkubyYCf1GiY/0))

Answer (score 1):

in your data you have 2 times ingredient 123 and 403, if you want to count them only one time you should use that query

```
SELECT
  COUNT(distinct(ri.rel_ingredient)) as allIngredient,
  COUNT(distinct(ri.rel_ingredient in (123,403))) have
FROM recipe_ingredient ri
GROUP BY ri.rel_recipe
```

Comment: no this doesn't work either, check https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/XhZs8yAyvRkubyYCf1GiY/6

Comment: @Gasper this query works fine, it returns the result you wrote in your post allIngredient: 6 and have: 2

Comment: yes if you try with both ingredients 123, 403 the result is ok but if you try with just one you would also get 2 which is wrong it should be 1...

Answer (score 0):

I prepared a solution but can someone check if this is the fastest solution. Check DB Fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/XhZs8yAyvRkubyYCf1GiY/10).

```
 SELECT r.id, r.name, 
    count(temp.rel_ingredients) as allIngredients,
    sum(temp.rel_ingredients in (123,403)) as have,
    (sum(temp.rel_ingredients in (123,403)) / count(temp.rel_ingredients)) as missing_ratio
 FROM (
  SELECT
    distinct(ri.rel_ingredient) as rel_ingredients,
    ri.rel_recipe
  FROM recipe_ingredient ri
) AS temp
LEFT JOIN recipe r ON r.id = temp.rel_recipe
GROUP BY temp.rel_recipe
HAVING have != 0
ORDER BY missing_ratio DESC, allIngredients DESC
LIMIT 0, 10;
```